# Почему smtplib работает не со всеми почтами?

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, smtp, smtplib

```
import smtplib 
EMAIL = 'email@email.com'
PASS_EMAIL = '**********'
email = "another@email.com"
smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
smtpObj.starttls()
smtpObj.login(EMAIL, PASS_EMAIL)
smtpObj.sendmail(EMAIL, email, "Hello, a message for testing!")
smtpObj.quit()
```

Если отсылаю на почту на gmail, то все работает. С яндеском через раз. mail.ru и rambler не работают — почта не доходит. Т.e., если я через gmail пытаюсь отправить письмо на другие почтовые сервисы, то не доходит оно до них (даже в спам нет). Как исправить?

Comment: `sendmail(EMAIL, email` — за названия переменных стоит больно стукнуть...

Comment: А вообще тело письма сформировано странно. Отсутствует From, отсутствует Subject, вообще заголовки никак не отделены от собственно тело — есть подозрение, что почтовые серверы просто отклоняют некорректно сформированное письмо

Comment: @andreymal Это так называемый минимальный воспроизводимый пример, переменная email была аргументом функции, так что стукнуть меня не надо. Я же не мог весь код выложить ;)

Comment: @andreymal Попробую с телом и т.д., но так это просто для тестинга.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 варианта отправки по смтп есть. Первый: логинишься в сервер отправителя, второй без авторизации в сервер получателя.

Во втором случае письмо лучше подписать через DKIM, иначе 50/50 попадешь в спам.

В первом случае домен почты должен принадлежать серверу.

Для ботов лучше запустить локальный smtp сервер и отправлять в него, а тот отправит на сервер получателя.

А ещё Mail.ru требует web авторизацию

Comment: Можете пример кода показать? ;)